# VBA ADODB Query Mysql returns character corruption

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, adodb, corruption

```
Sub hh()
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbConnStr As String
dbConnStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI DRIVER}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=landscape; USER=root; PASSWORD=mypass;"
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open dbConnStr
sql = "SELECT '東京都' AS tokyou"
rs.Open sql, con
Debug.Print rs!tokyou
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Returns things like "東・   "


[image]
I've tried:
1. use adodb.stream to convert query string to utf8, or otherwise convert query result to unicode
2. excute "set names = unicode;" in query
3. add "charset=unicode;" in connection string while open database connection

but none of them works, could you please help me, thanks!

Comment: What if you use `MySQL ODBC UNICODE Driver` instead of `ANSI`. It seems reasonable in your case

Comment: not sure what the last word means. You are welcome

Comment: "arigatou" = "Thank you" in Japanese :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using UNICODE characters. Please note that the ODBC driver comes in two flavours: ANSI and UNICODE. The latter is more appropriate to your situation. Use `MySQL ODBC UNICODE Driver` and you'll be good. Arigatou!