# How do I INSERT unicode symbols (such as Ohm/degree) with ODBC (MySQL) using VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, unicode, odbc, adodb

My VBA code snippet is:

```
        Set rsRecords = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        strQuery = Printf("INSERT INTO `parameters` (`name`) VALUES ('%s');", Cells(Row, 1).Text)
        MsgBox (strQuery)
        rsRecords.Open strQuery, oConn
```

The MsgBox properly displays the symbol (°) but MySQL Workbench shows me a (?) has been inserted instead. I can use Workbench to replace the ? with °, so I know it's not an issue with the DB table.

It appears the issue is in ADODB. Any ideas on how to fix?

Dan

Comment: Welcome to world of SQL Injection. What if user writes `x');DROP DATABASE db_name;--`?

Comment: Did you see the post re Unicode / ANSI - " use MySQL ODBC UNICODE Driver instead of ANSI"   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777214/vba-adodb-query-mysql-returns-character-corruption

Comment: What type is the `name` column? Is it a unicode type or a `varchar`? Also, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Very very curious about that `Printf` function. If it's anything like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534361/1188513) then it's a very cool thing to have, but not for anything that involves SQL strings.

Comment: The `name` column is VarChar and I was always able to store ° in it, I switched it to NVarChar and nothing changed. I am able to store ° in it from Workbench

The print function yields a string that includes °, I checked it with MsgBox.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn You nailed it, thanks!

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored